# Fibonacci sequence: Given $n$ and $\mathrm{Fib}(n)$, is it possible to calculate $\mathrm{Fib}(n-1)$?

Tags: fibonacci-numbers

Given $n$ and $\newcommand{\Fib}{\mathrm{Fib}} \Fib(n)$, is it possible to calculate the previous number in the Fibonacci sequence - $\Fib(n-1)$ using integer math in constant time? In other words, I believe I'm looking for a closed form formula.

For example: Given $n=10$ and $\Fib(10)=55$, I'd like to determine that $\Fib(9)=34$ without using $\Fib(7) + \Fib(8)$.

Comment: Even output of $F_{n-1}$ cannot be done in constant time. (The length of binary representation of $F_{n-1}$ is linear in $n$.) But based on the wording in original post I would guess that you mean using constantly many operations with integers.

Comment: @Martin Sleziak - you are correct that I meant "constantly many operations with integers"

Answer (score 5):

By [Binet's Formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinetsFibonacciNumberFormula.html), we know that $F_n = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(\phi^n-(-\phi)^{-n}\right) \approx \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\phi^n$ where $\phi = \dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$.

Using this formula, we can get that $F_{n-1}$ is the nearest integer to $\dfrac{1}{\phi} F_n$ for large $n$

More rigorously, we have $F_{n-1} - \dfrac{1}{\phi} F_n = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(\phi^{n-1}-(-\phi)^{-(n-1)}\right) - \dfrac{1}{\phi\sqrt{5}}\left(\phi^n-(-\phi)^{-n}\right)$ $= -\dfrac{(-\phi)^{-(n-1)}}{\sqrt{5}} - \dfrac{(-\phi)^{-(n+1)}}{\sqrt{5}}$ $= \dfrac{(-\phi)^{-n}}{\sqrt{5}}\left(\phi + \phi^{-1}\right) = (-\phi)^{-n}$.

Thus, for $n \ge 2$, we have $\left|F_{n-1} - \dfrac{1}{\phi} F_n \right| = \phi^{-n} < \frac{1}{2}$, and so, $F_{n-1}$ is the nearest integer to $\dfrac{1}{\phi}F_n$.

Dividing $F_n$ by $\phi$ and rounding the result to the nearest integer shouldn't be too computational.

Comment: Here is a table that shows the pattern:$$\begin{array} {c|c|c} n & a_n & a_n / a_{n-1} \\ \hline
0 & 0 & \\ \hline
1 & 1 & \\ \hline
2 & 1 &  1.0000 \\ \hline
3 & 2 &  2.0000 \\ \hline
4 & 3 &  1.5000 \\ \hline
5 & 5 &  1.6667 \\ \hline
6 & 8 &  1.6000 \\ \hline
7 & 13 &  1.6250 \\ \hline
8 & 21 &  1.6154 \\ \hline
9 & 34 &  1.6190 \\ \hline
10 & 55 &  1.6176 \\ \hline
11 & 89 &  1.6182 \\ \hline
12 & 144 &  1.6180 \\ \hline
13 & 233 &  1.6181 \\ \hline
14 & 377 &  1.6180 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Comment: @DanielV - agreed, this will work but as marty cohen points out in his anti-answer below, for large values of n simply rounding to the nearest integer will not necessarily yield the correct answer.

Answer (score 5):

This is a dissenting note on some of these answers.
I am purposly making this an answer,
though it really is an anti-answer.

The problem with any answer that uses $\phi$ is that, 
as $n$ gets larger, 
$\phi$ has to be computed with increasingly great precision. 
This will *not* take constant time,
either for the computation of $\phi$
or the multiplication by $\phi$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\rm\ n\:$ is a Fibonacci number iff the interval $\rm\ [\phi\ n - 1/n,\ \phi\ n + 1/n]\ $ contains a positive integer (the next Fibonacci number for $\rm\ n > 1)$. This follows from basic properties of continued fractions.

For example, $\rm\ 2 \to [2.7,\ 3.7],\ \ 3\to [4.5,\ 5.2],\ \ 5 \to [7.9,\ 8.3]\ \ldots$

For a proof see e.g. $ $ T. Komatsu: [The interval associated with a fibonacci number](http://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/41-1/komatsu.pdf). $\ $